# Printing just one group with printnomenclature?

Tags: nomenclature

I'm having trouble fitting my list of notations/nomenclature in one page for my thesis.  I tried looking for a solution to allow printing nomenclature across multiple pages and didn't find one.

My next thought is to use the groups to print one group at a time with `\printnomenclature`

Is it possible to print a single group with `\printnomenclature`?

Edit: Adding a minimum example (sorry for the length needed to push to multiple pages with columns)

**The `multicol`s use is what's causing the paging to fail (MWE pointed that out).  Is there a way to page with columns?**

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{multicol} 

% List of notations generation
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Notations}
%\nomlabelwidth=15mm
\makenomenclature
\makeindex

\begin{document}

    \begin{multicols}{2}

        \printnomenclature[2cm]
    \end{multicols} 


    \nomenclature{$a$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$b$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$c$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$d$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$e$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$f$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$a1$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$b1$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$c1$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$d1$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$e1$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$f1$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$a2$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$b2$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$c2$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$d2$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$e2$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$f2$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$a3$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$b3$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$c3$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$d3$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$e3$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$f3$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$a4$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$b4$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$c4$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$d4$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$e4$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$f4$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$1a$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$1b$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$1c$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$1d$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$1e$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$1f$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$1a1$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$1b1$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$1c1$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$1d1$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$1e1$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$1f1$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$1a2$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$1b2$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$1c2$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$1d2$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$1e2$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$1f2$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$1a3$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$1b3$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$1c3$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$1d3$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$1e3$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$1f3$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$1a4$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$1b4$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$1c4$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$1d4$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$1e4$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \nomenclature{$f4$}{Blah blah blah blah blah}

    asdf

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide an MWE. Like this, we will have to set up the whole problem for you. Thank you.

Comment: sure!  I was just hoping for any solution to page the listing or group by section/chapter.  One moment

Comment: Added - it's a multicols issue - any suggestions there?

Comment: I don't understand this question. What is the precise issue here?

Comment: The multicolumns doesnt extend to a second page - it just crops off at one page.

For now I'm just not using two columns :)

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't have flagged this up, possibly the question should be refocused into how can I print nomenclature across two columns.